# SelectOneMenu with filteroptions method in JSF2.0(Primefaces)

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

My requirement is similar to the below link
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf
but they write filteroptions in the column it self(3 rd column)Manufacturer,i also want to do the same thing but not in the column it outside the table. i.e before the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently supported out of box with Primefaces dataTables.

The only way to do this would be to implement custom filter fields and custom filtering logic in your managed bean to filter the table.  This may be difficult to do if you are implementing dynamic columns or lazy loading functionality in the dataTable.

Comment: please post any code related to this,because i have a little confusion regarding value change listener,is it required?

Comment: @rajeswari See this answer I provided to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175546/getting-the-filtered-list-in-datatable/9193168#9193168